# c - printing characters of multi-dimensional array in pairs

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2D array which holds characters that the user inputs. The user inputs two characters at a time like "AD", "TC", "2B", and "LM". I am trying to print the array out so it formats it as "AD, TC, 2B, LM" but right now it prints as "A, D, T, C, 2, B, L, M,"

I was wondering if there is a way to print the characters 2 by 2 like they were originally inputted by the user? Additionally, I would also like to get rid of the extra comma at the end.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        printf("%c,", usersAnswers[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current output is exactly what your `printf` and inner `for` loop are written to create. Change the `"%c, "` in your `printf` to `"%c"`, and then after your first `}` put `printf(",")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the printf(comma) position check before printing characters might be a solution. the first condition (i > 0) gets rid of the first and last comma. the second condition (j == 0) gets rid of the comma in a line.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        if(i > 0 && j == 0) { // add the print comma condition
            printf(",");
        }
        printf("%c", usersAnswers[i][j]);
    }
}
```

in short, print the comma before printing the first character in a line except the first line.